# GLES2 GL_BGR undeclared?

Tags: opengl-es2

I tried to bind a bitmap texture. This bitmap is BGR format, and I'm trying to use
`glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data)`, but during compile, error: 'GL_BGR' undeclared appears.

I checked `<GLES2/gl2.h>` and `<GLES2/gl2ext.h>`, but there isn't any `GL_BGR`
. Is there any way to upload BGR format?

Comment: https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/185197-Why-OpenGLES-2-spec-doesn-t-support-BGRA-texture-format

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately OpenGL ES2.0 does not support BGR texture formats in glTexImage2D.

> *format* determines the composition of each element in data. It can assume one of these symbolic values:
>
> - GL_ALPHA
> - GL_RGB
> - GL_RGBA
> - GL_LUMINANCE
> - GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA

Source: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml